# Как БЕЗОПАСНО сбрасывать кэш первого уровня?

Tags: java, hibernate

Столкнулся с тем, что при редактировании одной из строк, мне при запросе возвращаются старые данные.
Как в последствии выяснилось, он банально грузит его заново из кэша 1го уровня.
Стал перед нужными запросам сбрасывать его с помощью:

```
session.clear();
```

Но теперь возникает проблема при нескольких обновлениях одного и того же объекта:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value     was already associated with the session:
```

Подсобите, может надо по другому решать эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось порыться...
Суть в том что после `.clear()` ошибка срабатывает только при команде `.update()` или `.saveOrUpdate()`. 
Решение я нашел [тут](http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/). Если коротко то эту команду надо заменить на `.merge(Object o)`